# Trim long html for preview without breaking html tags

Tags: html, regex

I was put in front of this problem when working on a blog post preview list.
They need to shorten the content but not break any html tags by leaving them open.

I have heard that reg ex is not a good option. I am looking for something simple and working.

I appreciate your help in advance as always (SO ended up being a very nice place to come over with problems like that :-)

Comment: The application I work on is a ASP.NET MVC3 website and using C#. I don't use any plugins and wrote the blog engine from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a function for generating excerpts built-in to the blogging platform which generates an [excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt) from the actual blog post.

You didn't specify which language you were looking to use for the trim function so here is the Wordpress version. It can be easily modified and re-purposed to use outside of Wordpress if need be.

[wp_trim_words() function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

```
/**
 * Generates an excerpt from the content, if needed.
 *
 * The excerpt word amount will be 55 words and if the amount is greater than
 * that, then the string ' [&hellip;]' will be appended to the excerpt. If the string
 * is less than 55 words, then the content will be returned as is.
 *
 * The 55 word limit can be modified by plugins/themes using the excerpt_length filter
 * The ' [&hellip;]' string can be modified by plugins/themes using the excerpt_more filter
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $text Optional. The excerpt. If set to empty, an excerpt is generated.
 * @return string The excerpt.
 */
function wp_trim_excerpt($text = '') {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');

        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
```